# How do I find the most common string in a column by replacing?

Tags: excel-formula

Suppose I have a column of wind directions ("N","S","W",E"). Each cell only contains 1 letter. If I am to find the most common wind directions,`=CHAR(MODE(CODE(range)))` will do the job
But if I handle wind directions like "SW","NE", the above function would not work. I know that `=INDEX(range, MODE(MATCH(range, range, 0 )))` will work.

Just curious, somewhat similar to the first function, is there a way to substitue strings with numbers of choice only when passing in the column into `MODE()`function, so that it will return a number for me to `MATCH()` and `INDEX()` to get the result?

Clarify: Say that I have the following data
[image: ![enter image description here]

And I would like to substitue "N" with 0, "NE" with 45, "SW" with 225 and so on. So that `MODE()` will be applicable. And if needed, I can then use functions like `INDEX(MATCH())` to return the actual letter representation of the wind direction.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean with example data and examples of numbers of choice?

Comment: Clarification added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=SWITCH(MODE(SWITCH(A:A,"N",0,"NE",45,"E",90,"SE",135,"S",180,"SW",225,"W",270,"NW",315,"")),0,"N",45,"NE",90,"E",135,"SE",180,"S",225,"SW",270,"W",315,"NW","")`

Or similar:

`=CHOOSE(1+MODE(SWITCH(A:A,"N",0,"NE",45,"E",90,"SE",135,"S",180,"SW",225,"W",270,"NW",315,""))/45,"N","NE","E","SE","S","SW","W","NW")`

This first translates the strings to values, then translates the MODE result back to it's string.